# How to return the multiple indexes of word using .index in Python

Tags: python

I am struggling with the command .index in Python. I want to be able to enter a sentence and then Python to return the multiple indexes of the word I choose. For example if I enter the sentence "i love you you love me we all love barney" and then choose the word "love" I want it to return "2","5","9". But instead my code only will return the first one, "2".

```
sentence = input("Enter a sentence")
word = input("Enter the word")
position = sentence.index(word)
print(position)
```

Please can you help me edit this code so it return more than one index of the chosen word.

Thanks

Comment: @Anton Why 9 and 11

Comment: Sorry, mistake, I think you want reel pos in string ('l' of 'love' pos). But you want pos of word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (Note: the index of the first word will be `0`) and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
s = "i love you you love me we all love barney"
for word_index, word in enumerate(s.split()):
    if word == "love":
        print(word_index)
```

Output:

```
1
4
8
```

Answer (score 0):

.index only return the first occurrence. You can try this:

```
position = [idx+1 for idx,w in enumerate(sentence.split()) if w == word]
print(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words in the sentence with a space and then search for a particular word.

For example:

```
textSplit = sentence.split(' ')
for i in range(len(textSplit)):
   if textSplit[i] == word:
      print i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
indices = [i+1 for i, x in enumerate(sentence.split()) if x == word]
```

indices contains all the position